# Why is DbContext (ASP.NET) null in MyService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, startup, dbcontext

I use c#, ASP.NET Core, EF.

I have Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            ...
        }
```

I have Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public AppDbContext _db;

        public HomeController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
         // _db is NOT NULL           
         var d = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault();
        }
}
```

I have class MyService.cs:

```
public class MyService
{
        public static AppDbContext _db;

        public MyService(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public static void GetOtherValue()
        {   
             // _db is NULL           
             var d = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault();
        }
  }
```

HomeController works correctly: **_db** is not null.

Why variable **_db is null in MyService.cs**? How to fix it?

**UP:**

```
public class OtherController : Controller
{
    ....
    MyService.GetOtherValue();
    ....
}
```

Comment: did you register dbcontext && service class into DI? Why the field is static? How is service class created?

Comment: Is the service declared as a service, and how is the service initalized? Should be DI.

Comment: Where do you inject the service?

Comment: updated question

Comment: how to make DI?

Comment: @Olga check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not injecting your service anywhere.

You just use static method thus constructor is never called. You can inject through the constructor.

First add a service into ASP.Net Core container:

```
services.AddScoped<MyService, MyService>();
```

Then inject via constructor in your controller class:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyService _myService;

    public HomeController (MyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
}
```

`MyService` class will be created every requests ( `AddScoped()`). Then the your `DbContext` will be created automatically.

[Read more about DI in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)